# A tough riddle - What am I?

Tags: riddle

> We go everywhere together.
>   You bite me, but that doesn't mean that you're tough.
>   You're not tough enough to eat me.
>   Only the hardest are compared to I.
>   I will bring about the end, in your place of final resting.
>   And with me as a resting place, you would not lie comfortably.
>   I'm known for success and perfection.
>   You'll go for my head, when you know what I am.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expanding on @lois6b's answer

> Nails (Both finger/toe nails and hardware nails)

We go everywhere together.

> Almost everyone has finger/toe nails and takes them with them

You bite me, but that doesn't mean that you're tough.

> Can be bitten but nail-biting is synonymous with worrying, not exactly tough

You're not tough enough to eat me.

> Most people wouldn't eat hardware nails. From OP; 'He looks like he ate nails for breakfast' is a phrase describing someone who looks tough.

Only the hardest are compared to I.

> Consider the phrase 'Hard as nails' describing a tough person

I will bring about the end, in your place of final resting.

> Consider the phrase 'Final nail in the coffin'

And with me as a resting place, you would not lie comfortably.

> The 'lying on a bed of nails' feat, hardly considered comfortable

I'm known for success and perfection.

> Consider the phrase 'Nailed it!', an utterance when succeeding with style

You'll go for my head, when you know what I am.

> Consider the phrase 'Hit the nail on the head' both literally and figuratively.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it is the more correct one.

Comment: Although what you said for Line 3 is correct, there is an idiom about eating <answer> that I had in mind and it is supposed to mean that someone looks tough. Ie. He looks like he ate <answer> for breakfast. Aside from that, spot on.

Comment: Ah yes, I thought there may be a phrase concerning that, cheers I'll edit it in.

Comment: The third last hint - It's not that uncomfortable, if setup correctly.

Answer (score 9):

Answer is

> Nails

We go everywhere together.

> We all have'em.

You bite me, but that doesn't mean that you're tough.

> People with anxiety are usually pictured biting their nails.

You're not tough enough to eat me.

> [Eat nail](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/eat+nails)

Only the hardest are compared to I.

> Tough as Nail

I will bring about the end, in your place of final resting.

> Coffins are secure with nails.

And with me as a resting place, you would not lie comfortably.

> Lying on nails is known to be uncomfortably.

I'm known for success and perfection.

> To nail something is to do it perfectly.

You'll go for my head, when you know what I am.

> You'll type the answer, probably using the tip of the nail too

Comment: I eat them.....

Comment: This may be the answer, but maybe if you think of the metal version of this word there will be better explanations for some of the lines.  (final resting = coffin... <blank> in the coffin) (saying of "tough as <blank>)  Some resting places are a "bed of <blank>", etc.

Comment: I suspect that this is right, but the reasoning is a little off in places.

Comment: I would edit, but there is a "pending edit"?  Another line would be to "hit the <blank> on the head for success and perfection.

Comment: This is correct. But there are a lot of idioms that need explaining. Lines 3, 4, 5 ,7 and 8 should be looked at again :)

Comment: Filling in the gaps for lois6b:

3/4 - As hard as nails is an idiom for very strong, like something that is nailed together (also heard as tough as nails meaning a similar thing)

5 - Put the nail in the coffin - to finish something off

7 - To nail something is to do it perfectly/successfully

8 - To hit the nail on the head is to get the correct answer

Comment: Some tips: Line 4: There is the saying "Tough as nails", Line 5: Many old coffins were nailed shut. Last line: Once you know the answer you start typing it out, thus probably touching the keyboard with the top part of the nail(head) while doing so

Comment: very nice @vanillagod

Comment: this is endless. everyone have nice edits! :_D

Comment: well yeah but without the comments would be incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

I think

> Brain

## Explanation

```
We go everywhere together.
```

> The brain is in your head always, you can't live without it.

```
You're not tough enough to eat me.
```

> You can't eat your brain lol

```
Only the hardest are compared to I.
```

> Everyone has a brain, but there are some genious.

```
I will bring about the end, in your place of final resting.
```

> When You die, Your brain dead too.

```
I'm known for success and perfection.
```

> The brain is perfect.

Comment: Nice attempt, but its incorrect.

Comment: Hi! You might consider putting your explanation behind spoiler tags as well.

Comment: Ok. @hypern Sorry, I must delete it?

Comment: @Ronronner You don't have to apologise for providing an answer! You certainly don't have to delete it either.

Comment: Ok.  I'm new in this site and I'm solving problem solving/logic quiz etc. since few time

Answer (score 3):

> Teeth?

We go everywhere together.

> You have em in your mouth

You bite me, but that doesn't mean that you're tough.

> You bite with them

You're not tough enough to eat me.

> No you're not.

Only the hardest are compared to I.

> Hardest in body

I will bring about the end, in your place of final resting.

> Eaten in grave?

And with me as a resting place, you would not lie comfortably.

> Don't want to be eaten

I'm known for success and perfection.

> ???

You'll go for my head, when you know what I am.

> Teeth are in head

Comment: Its not teeth, but its an interesting answer.

Comment: for success i think its like: white teeth means wealthy

Answer (score 2):

Answer is

> SHOES

We go everywhere together.

> each for 1 leg.

You bite me, but that doesn't mean that you're tough.

> sometimes shoes bite if not correct size.

You're not tough enough to eat me.

> but shoes can't eat us.

I will bring about the end, in your place of final resting.

> Where you leave your shoes after we come to home.

Comment: Its not the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you my

> Tongue

We go everywhere together.

> Your tongue is generally part of you

You bite me, but that doesn't mean that you're tough.

> Many people bite their tongues, and it usually hurts

You're not tough enough to eat me.

> No matter who you are, you aren't likely to eat your own tongue

Only the hardest are compared to I.

> Not sure here. My initial thought was putting your money where your mouth is, but that is weak

I will bring about the end, in your place of final resting.

> Those around you will eulogize you after your death

And with me as a resting place, you would not lie comfortably.

> First thought is cannibalism, but that seems wrong

I'm known for success and perfection.

> Some allusion to silver tongued people?

You'll go for my head, when you know what I am.

> Oh, the answer is on the tip of my tongue...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> Money (coins)

We go everywhere together.

> almost everybody has money with them

You bite me, but that doesn't mean that you're tough.

> in old times people used to bite gold coins to see if it was real?

And with me as a resting place, you would not lie comfortably.

> coins are not very comfortable to lie on

I'm known for success and perfection.

> people associate money with success (and perfection?)

You'll go for my head, when you know what I am.

> everybody wants money. head could refer to the head side of a coin but it probably refers to the faces  on banknotes, which you would want because they are worth more